# Writing Read access permission for Custom Content provider?

Tags: android, permissions, android-contentprovider

I have made a `ContentProvider`, how do I allow other applications to read data from this `ContentProvider` only when they mention permission to read data from this `ContentProvider`?

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134752/android-contentprovider-read-and-write-permissions