# ContentProvider with exported=false

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am going through the documentation for the contentprovider "exported" attribute [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/provider-element.html#exported)

Can someone pleas explain what does this statement mean :

> *You can set android:exported="false" and still limit access to your provider by setting permissions with the permission attribute*

I always thought with exported=false, none of the external apps can access the provider. But the above statement seems contradictory.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Your understanding of `exported = false` is right. It will block access to the `contentProvider` to everyone.

However, with right `permissions` (read/write) you can create 'exceptions' so that only apps with permissions will be able to access the content Provider even if it is blocked for every other app.

also, [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7134752/android-contentprovider-read-and-write-permissions)

Comment: With right permissions - I need the exported=true to make them work correct ?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is just a typo. And what it means is that you can 'allow access' by setting it to `true` and that you can use permissions to limit what applications can access the content provider.

I'll look into this, since I help *teach* this material... (will update)

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was thinking. But just wasnt sure. Please update with your findings. Thanks again.